# Proof for Discrete Math Noticing

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The other day while biking I realized that if you multiply a single digit number by a multi digit number, and then add the digits together until you got to a single digit number, it would have the same final digit as if you added the multi digit number together before multiplying.

For example, $423 \cdot 7=2961, 2+9+6+1=18, 1+8=9$, while $(4+2+3) \cdot 7=63, 6+3=9$.

How would one go about writing a proof for this, or does one already exist? I'm not super into math, just like playing with numbers while I ride my bike, so thought this was interesting, and was curious as to the why of it.

Comment: a number and the sum of its digits are the same $\pmod 9$

Comment: See also [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

Comment: A number like $2961=2\cdot 10^3+9\cdot 10^2+6\cdot 10 +1$ and $10$ is congruent to $1$ mod $9$.